# how to append a data at a list and plot it with python plotly

Tags: python, append, plotly

hi there i m still trying to get trade bot and try to plot them with their time and low price data. 
i wanna get buy signals that i ve specified at if condition (when macdh turns from negative to positive). then i want to plot them at a data. but can not add them at **buy_signal=[]** place.
my error is 
**self.plotData(buy_signals = buy_signals)
IndexError: list index out of range**

````
import requests
import json
from stockstats import StockDataFrame as Sdf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot


class TradingModel:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = self.getData


    def getData(self):

        # define URL
        base = 'https://api.binance.com'
        endpoint = '/api/v3/klines'
        params = '?&symbol='+self.symbol+'&interval=4h'

        url = base + endpoint + params

        # download data
        data = requests.get(url)
        dictionary = data.json()

        # put in dataframe and clean-up
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
        df = df.drop(range(6, 12), axis=1)


        # rename columns and stockstasts
        col_names = ['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
        df.columns = col_names
        stock = Sdf.retype(df)


        for col in col_names:
            df[col]=df[col].astype(float)
        #defined macdh
        df['macdh']=stock['macdh']


        return  (df)

    def strategy(self):
        df = self.df
        buy_signals=[]
        for i in range(1, len(df['close'])):
                if df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0:
                    buy_signals.append([df['time'][i], df['low'][i]])

        self.plotData(buy_signals = buy_signals)





    def plotData(self,buy_signal=False):
        df=self.df
        candle=go.Candlestick(
            x=df['time'],
            open=df['open'],
            close=df['close'],
            high=df['high'],
            low=df['low'],
            name="Candlesticks"
        )
        macdh=go.Scatter(
            x=df['time'],
            y=df['macdh'],
            name="Macdh",
            line = dict(color=('rgba(102, 207, 255, 50)')))

        Data=[candle,macdh]

        if buy_signals:
            buys = go.Scatter(
                    x = [item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                    y = [item[1] for item in buy_signals],
                    name = "Buy Signals",
                    mode = "markers",
                )

            sells = go.Scatter(
                    x = [item[0] for item in buy_signals],
                    y = [item[1]*1.04 for item in buy_signals],
                    name = "Sell Signals",
                    mode = "markers",
                )

            data = [candle, macdh, buys, sells]


        # style and display
        layout = go.Layout(title = self.symbol)
        fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)

        plot(fig, filename=self.symbol)

def Main():
    symbol = "BTCUSDT"
    model = TradingModel(symbol)
    model.strategy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main() ```
````

Comment: it would be helpful if you could make it more readable by only posting the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Why are you cross-posting this in r? Any r relevant question you have?

Comment: @ShanR sorry i ve posted suggested ones i m editing it

Comment: @EmmaH if i can ad buy signal list others will be done

Comment: I cannot actually find self.plotData(buy_signals[i]) in your code, only self.plotData(buy_signals = buy_signals)

Comment: @EmmaH when i editing it i ve forget to fix it i m editing it too
self.plotData(buy_signals = buy_signals) wrong place is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace :

`self.plotData(buy_signals[i])` by `self.plotData(buy_signals)`

`def plotData(self,buy_signal=False):` by `def plotData(self,buy_signals=None):`

And it should be good to go !

Comment: it works but i got another problem.
 if buy_signals==True:
NameError: name 'buy_signals' is not defined

Comment: when i type this mate buysignals list is empty

Comment: I can't see any `if buy_signals==True:` in your code

Comment: when i add [print(buy_signals)] under if condition i got a empty list

Comment: if df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0:
     buy_signals.append([df['time'][i], df['low'][i]])
    print(buy_signals)
this list is empty

Comment: It's probably empty because no buy signal is triggered. Said differently, the condition `if df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0:` is never met, so nothing is appended to the `buy_signals` list

Comment: when i wanna print macdh i can get numbers and stock is a table with Emas and macd values.

Comment: Yes i know, having values in `df['macdh']` allows to compute the `df['macdh'].iloc[-1]>0 and df['macdh'].iloc[-2]<0:` evaluation, but if the condition is never met the list is never appended to